Why am I here? What about my dad?
We are both quite nerdy, but he often has to call me for tech support.

Hint 1:

 My dad is a chemist. I like computers.


Va purzvfgel, n oynpx urkntba vf bsgra hfrq nf n ercerfragngvba bs fvk pneoba ngbzf pbaarpgrq gbtrgure va n urkntba. Znlor gung pbhyq or eryngrq gb guvf dhrfgvba. (rot13)

I see

 a hexagon and an impossible geometry.

 I have a wild idea that it might have something to do with the London Stock Exchange before 1986 when it had hexagonal booths.

 You are caught in a time warp and need a fix for the nerdy time machine.


A cool idea, but unfortunately, this wasn't the intended answer. I now see how the clue in the text might've been a red herring, so I'll clarify it slightly.
hint in rot13: uryvxrfpurzvfgel. vyvxrpbzchgref.

OK, I see you've removed the reference to Stack Exchange which gave the parallel universe. Hmm, are you referring to a rot13(oramrar evat)? Perhaps hints should be edited into the question.

rot13(lbhnervaqrrqpbeerpg.)
Regarding the hint being edited into the question, I might well do that.

the "O" is rot13(gur ybtb bs WFBA)

Ok, let's give it a "what the heck, it's friday"-shot.
I'd go with

 Michael and Kirk Douglas.

Why?

 As already mentioned, we see a picture of a benzene-ring and the JSON-logo combined.
 JSON was spezified by Douglas Crockford, benzene was first isolated and identified by Michael Faraday.

 If I combine these names, I end up with the actor Michael Douglas - and of course his father Kirk.

 However, I can't find a (imho proper) connection between Michael and the "I like computer"-phrase. Apart perhaps from the film "Disclosure".

 Whereas (according to my sources), Kirk Douglas graduated as a bachalor at St. Lawrence University in Chemistry (and English literature) 1939.

